# jsPDF not printing properly

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am having problem with the pdf document not printing properly when I have a name as **こん** , but afterwards it prints as **S**. I want it to be printed out as **こん**

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
var name = "こん";

doc.addFont('fonts/arial-unicode-ms/ArialUnicodeMS.TTF', 'ArialUnicodeMS', 'normal');
doc.setFont('ArialUnicodeMS');
doc.text(10, 28, name);

doc.save("example.pdf")
```

Comment: Works for me no problem. Are you sure its loading the font?

Comment: How can I check? If it loads? Once I saves it gives that **S**

Comment: When I removed the line that loads the font, I got a warning when running my code. It produced wrong output, but it wasn't the same as what you got. I got `0S0“`. IS the font present in a sub folder `fonts/arial-unicode-ms` relative to where the program is run?

Comment: The file `ArialUnicodeMS.TTF` is shown in that directory, but it looks like theres a whole lot of random characters(mostly **?**) in the file, it might be encoded not sure

Comment: Worth downloading the font again?